# Laptop Keyboard issue - is it a virus?

Tags: keyboard, virus

My girlfriend's laptop (an eee pc) just started malfunctioning, and it looks to me like  a virus - the keyboard is not working at all, yet sending keypresses anyway, resulting in crazy beeps any time the laptop is on. It also types characters repeatedly without a key being pressed.

Windows media player also appears intermittently.

Has anyone here any idea if this is a virus, or better still, know how to fix the issue?

Comment: Could please try to start a Live-CD (or a Live-System from USB Stick) to verify that it is not the hardware?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds as if the keyboard is just malfunctioning, which would also explain for WMP popping up. Although I wouldn't rule it out, i doubt a virus would be doing what your girlfriend is experiencing.

You could confirm this by booting into a 'live cd' linux distro (If you don't have a USB CD drive, just extract the .iso to a flash drive) and seeing if the keyboard functions the same.

Ig the keyboard is misbehaving, I suggest you call Asus support and get it repaired (assuming it is still under warranty)